# Making TextBox smaller

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Right now I'm working on a project and need to change the size of a `Textbox` and make it smaller.

When I try to change it's height and widgth from design page the text is getting cut and I can't prevent this just by changing text's size.

Do you havae any clue about this?

Thank you.

Comment: In most cases a dynamic width and height are advisable, especially if you plan on localizing the app later. If you really need to, you should be able to change the height with the font size. Be aware that you might need to set `TextWrapping="Wrap"`. Also, some XAML would be helpful here :)

Comment: What's the UI?  Winform, WPF, HTML, etc?

Answer (score 3):

To change height and width, use `MinHeight` and `MinWidth` properties and then adjust font using `FontSize` property.

Comment: MinHeight and MinWidth is already 0 how can i make it smaller?